# Acceder a los campos de las relaciones usando with - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$estructura = User::with('posts.comments')->get()
```

Esto me devuelve lo siguiente

```
[
  {
    "id_usuario": "1",
    "user_info_id": "1",
    "posts": [
      {
        "id_post": "1",
        "usuario_id": "1",
        "titulo":"Nuevo Post",
        "categoria_id":"1",
        "comments": [
          {
            "comment_post_id":"1",
            "post_id": "1",
            "comentario":"Un comentario"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

En mi tabla `user_info` tengo los campos: `user_info_id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `direccion` y `telefono`

En mi tabla `categorias` tengo: `categoria_id`, `categoria_nombre`, `descripcion`

En  mi tabla `usuarios`, tengo: `id_usuario` y `user_info_id`

En mi tabla `posts`, tengo: `id_post`, `usuario_id`, `titulo` y `categoria_id`

En mi tabla `comments`, tengo: `comment_post_id`, `post_id` y `comentario`

Como pueden ver, estoy usando el `with` para obtener dicha estructura, pero lo que quiero es que me muestre en vez del `user_info_id` y `categoria_id`, los campos que tienen como `nombre` o `categoria_nombre`. Como podria hacerlo?

Resultado que quiero:

```
[
  {
    "id_usuario": "1",
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "posts": [
      {
        "id_post": "1",
        "usuario_id": "1",
        "titulo":"Nuevo Post",
        "categoria_nombre":"discusión",
        "comments": [
          {
            "comment_post_id":"1",
            "post_id": "1",
            "comentario":"Un comentario"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Cabe resaltar que esto lo estoy usando como ejemplo (post, comments) pero las relaciones serian:

```
Uno a muchos: User->post, Post->comments, Post->categorias
Uno a uno: User->user_info
```

**Modelo User**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_usuario';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post', 'usuario_id');
    }

    public function user_info()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserInfo', 'user_info_id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Posts**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Post;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_posts';

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comments', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: @BetaM Lo estoy usando como ejemplo, pero si quieres, puedo implementar los modelos mostrando el `hasMany` y el `hasOne`

Comment: Esto de dónde sale por ejemplo user_info_id? Es decir está en el modelo user?

Comment: Si esta en mi tabla usuarios

Comment: las relaciones que indicas existen entre tus entidades son unas y las columnas que indicas cada tabla tienen son otras y no se corresponden, por ejemplo indicas esto: **Uno a muchos: User->post** pero luego tu tabla post solo tiene estas columnas: **id_post, titulo y categoria_id** y ahi ya te esta faltando el id del usuario. y asi por el estilo con las demás, cuando eso quede resuelto hacer las relaciones en Eloquent será muy fácil y podemos seguir

Comment: @BetaM como dije lo estoy tomando como ejemplo así que lo hize mentalmente, se me olvidaron colocar dichas relaciones, disculpa. En contexto un usuario puede hacer muchos posts y un post puede tener muchos comentarios, la solución que veo a mi problema es que en los modelos, tengo que agregar algo pero no se que

Comment: ok @juan con base en las relaciones indicadas te armaré una respuesta, ya luego te encargas tu de hacer las modificaciones en tu base de datos

Comment: @BetaM gracias, siempre uso ejemplos para hacer mis preguntas porque no me gusta el copy paste de mi duda, si la respuesta es correcta, lo modificare y agregare cosas que faltarían para solucionar mi problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para completar las relaciones por medio de Eloquent, debes llevar a cabo los siguientes pasos:

1. Si las llaves primarias no tienen el nombre esperado entonces declaralas como atributo de la clase
2. Si el nombre de la tabla no corresponde a lo esperado por Eloquent, entonces declaralo como atributo de clase
3. Si las llaves foráneas no corresponden a la estructura esperada, entonces pasalo como segundo argumento en la declaración de la relación; así:

   ```
   ->hasMany(Post::class, 'llave_foranea');
   ```
4. Como además tu llave primaria no tiene el nombre esperado, entonces en esa misma declaración debes pasar como tercer argumento el nombre de la misma quedando así:

   ```
   ->hasMany(Post::class, 'llave_foranea', 'llave_primaria');
   ```
5. Para el caso del modelo `Post`, tu llave foránea si no cumple con los criterios de Eloquent entonces también la debes declarar así:

   ```
   ->belongsTo(User::class, 'llave_foranea');
   ```
6. Además como la llave primaria del modelo `User` es distinta a lo esperado entonces la declaramos como tercer argumento así:

   ```
   ->belongsTo(User::class, 'llave_foranea', 'llave_de_entidad_user');
   ```

Estos mismos pasos son los que tienes que considerar para el caso de la relación entre `Post` y `Comment`.

Cuando tengas todos los puntos anteriores en orden entonces podrás obtener la data esperada con la consulta que de hecho **ya tienes**

**Comentarios finales**

- Como se puede observar en la propia doc. oficial los pasos son similares para el caso de la relación 1 a 1
- Te puedes *ahorrar* todas estas configuraciones extra si en la medida de lo posible sigues las convenciones que da Eloquent.

Ahora bien para constuir la consulta puedes hacerlo así:

```
User::with(['user_info', 'posts.comments'])->get();
```

Tal como lo indica la documentación [justo aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships) para *cargar* múltiples relaciones

**Fuentes de consulta**

- [Relación uno a muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [Convenciones de modelos de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Vale, acá solo se esta tomando `User` y `Posts`, tengo que hacer algo con la tabla `user_info`? Porque de ahi quiero sus datos como `nombre`

Comment: no la incluí por que me comentabas que me basara en users, posts y comments, cual es la relación entre users e user_info? lo pregunto para agregarlo a mi respùesta

Comment: Es de uno a uno

Comment: @JuanRivera la lógica es exactamente la misma para las llaves primaria y foráneas como argumentos de las relaciones: [aquí lo puedes leer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Podrias decirme la consulta? Porque utilizo `$estructura = User::with('posts.comments')->get()`. Solo accedo a `post` y dentro de este a `comments`, pero en ningun momento a `user_info`. Si bien en mi modelo `User` esta relacionado eso, lo pongo para que lo entiendas, mira mi modelo  `User`

Comment: listo @JuanRivera edité y agregué la consulta

Comment: Gracias, solo solo me faltaba eso `['user_info', 'posts.comments']`, a reaprender con la doc